# Clip (Data Management) tool with basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, arcgis-10.5, basemap, csw

Can the Clip (Data Management) tool can be used with a basemap?

I tried without success.

If yes, how can it be used?

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1.

I want just cut the image of my property. The sources of images of my property are the basemap "imagery" and aerophotos from my arcgis csw client. With aerophotos (.grid) from other local i could use the Clip tool to cut as i want in my property, but with basemap and client csw i can't.

Comment: Dublicate of [Using Clip (Data Management) tool and client CSW?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283655/using-clip-data-management-tool-and-client-csw)

Answer (score 1):

Click the View menu, choose Data Frame options. At the bottom of the Data Frame Tab are "Clip Options" Choose Clip to Shape then click the Specify Shape button. On the next screen you can choose the layer you want to use as the shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking to get as a result? 
============================================================================If you want to clip data based on extents of features (i.e. clip drinking fountains within City Boundary) based on information from basemap - it is next to impossible as the basemap is just a bunch of raster images (tiles) arranged on the screen at appropriate resolution, and you will need source data (i.e. City Boundary shapefile) features for geoprocessing.

Comment: I want just cut the image of my property. The sources of images of my property are the basemap "imagery" and aerophotos from my arcgis  csw client. With aerophotos (.grid) from other local i could use the Clip tool to cut as i want in my property, but with basemap and client csw i can't.

Comment: Try lambertj suggestion, from my understanding this is the only way to accomplish what you want in ArcMap.

Comment: The suggestion from lambertj dont create a layer, just crop the basemap.

Comment: You will not be able to create a layer from a basemap as it is already an aggregate of multiple rasters. If you need the basemap as a layer, you will need to find original raster datasets that fed into the imagery.

Comment: Rus 2, do you know how can i find this original raster?

Comment: Depending on what you want specifically. I'm not sure what imagery was used for ESRI satellite imagery. Try looking at USGS Earth explorer if Landsat 30 m resolution is sufficient for you. If you need a high-resolution imagery (i.e. 1 m), you can either look up your municipal website, as in North America most large cities periodically collect aerial imagery, or you can try commercial products like Digital Globe.

Comment: My case is in Brazil.The municipal or state website have not the aerial imagery available for the public as in North America.